# Limit won't compute

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax

Does anyone know why the limit:

```
Limit[(α*(E^((t*ϵ)/(λ*τ))*t*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ) - E^((t*ϵ)/(λ*τ))*ϵ*(-1 + 
    2*λ)*τ + E^((t*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ))/((-1 + λ)*λ*τ))*ϵ*(-1 + λ)*(1 + (-2 + ϵ)*λ)*τ + 
    ϵ*λ*(-1 + ϵ + 2*λ - ϵ*λ)*τ))/(E^((t*ϵ)/(λ*τ))*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ)), 
  λ -> 0
]
```

won't compute?

Sorry about the weird formatting.

Comment: Thanks Halirutan for cleaning up that code.

Comment: I haven't looked in detail, but typically the result would depend on the parameters and it's difficult or impossible to get a result without knowing something about them.  Example quiz: *What's the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-a x}$?*   If you said zero, that's not correct.  The correct answer is $0$ if $a>0$, $\infty$ if $a < 0$ and $1$ if $a=0$.  And that still assumed that $a$ is real.  Correspondingly `Limit[Exp[-a x], x -> Infinity]` gives you nothing but `Limit[Exp[-a x], x -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a > 0]` does respond `0`.

Comment: Keep in mind that by default Mathematica assumes that any parameter can take any complex value, which makes the problem very difficult.  Generally one needs to specify assumptions about the parameters to get a solution.

Comment: I completely agree with Szabolcs. Just throwing a large expression at *Mathematica* is often useless. I guess a more promising approach is to go to [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) and ask how you could tackle this problem by hand and then do the sub-steps in *Mathematica*. In the not so complex sub-steps you are probably able to determine what goes wrong when *Mathematica* does not evaluated an expression as you expect it.

Comment: I see: I added the appropriate assumptions and got a solution. Thanks again for helping me today. I'm sure that the 'Assumptions->...' specification command will come in handy in the future too.

Comment: Thanks guys. This was more of a question of how Mma was handling the situation than how to find this specific answer. Problem solved. Assumptions need to be specified.

Comment: Just an additional comment: symbolic algebra systems make mistakes.  It's wise not to trust them blindly.  But they're also very useful, especially if the problem is straightforward but laborious.  So what I'd do here to have some more confidence (other than numerical verification) is this: 1. get rid of α because it's just a constant factor.  2. `Expand` the expression and examine the terms.  Notice that carrying out the limit is quite trivial, so Mma is unlikely to make mistakes. ...

Comment: ... 3.  `Map` the limit onto the sum hoping that we won't get a cancelling sum of infinities: `Assuming[\[Tau] > 0 && t > 0 && \[Epsilon] > 0, 
 Limit[Expand[expr], \[Lambda] -> 0]]`.  This gives a good result (and the same as the direct question), which will improve your confidence in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of having an answer (more or less given in the comments):

```
Limit[
  (α*(E^((t*ϵ)/(λ*τ))*t*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ) -
       E^((t*ϵ)/(λ*τ))*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ)*τ +
       E^((t*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ))/((-1 + λ)*λ*τ))*ϵ*(-1 + λ)*(1 + (-2 + ϵ)*λ)*τ +
       ϵ*λ*(-1 + ϵ + 2*λ - ϵ*λ)*τ)) /
   (E^((t*ϵ)/(λ*τ))*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ)),
  λ -> 0, Direction -> -1,
  Assumptions -> t ϵ τ > 0]
(*
   α (t + (-1 + E^(-((t ϵ)/τ))) τ)
*)
```

The OP is welcome to post their own answer, too!

Answer (score 2):

```
f=(α*(E^((t*ϵ)/(λ*τ))*t*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ) -
       E^((t*ϵ)/(λ*τ))*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ)*τ +
       E^((t*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ))/((-1 + λ)*λ*τ))*ϵ*(-1 + λ)*(1 + (-2 + ϵ)*λ)*τ +
       ϵ*λ*(-1 + ϵ + 2*λ - ϵ*λ)*τ)) /
   (E^((t*ϵ)/(λ*τ))*ϵ*(-1 + 2*λ))//Expand;
```

One use

```
Limit[#, λ -> 0] & /@ f
```

and get
$\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \, \frac{2 \alpha  \lambda ^2 \tau  e^{-\frac{t \epsilon }{\lambda  \tau }}}{2 \lambda -1}+\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \, -\frac{\alpha  \lambda ^2 \tau  \epsilon  e^{-\frac{t \epsilon }{\lambda  \tau }}}{2 \lambda -1}+\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \, \frac{\alpha  \lambda  \tau  \epsilon  e^{-\frac{t \epsilon }{\lambda  \tau }}}{2 \lambda -1}+\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \, -\frac{\alpha  \lambda  \tau  e^{-\frac{t \epsilon }{\lambda  \tau }}}{2 \lambda -1}-\alpha  \tau +\alpha  \tau  e^{-\frac{t \epsilon }{\tau }}+\alpha  t.$

One can see clearly the limit of each subexpression. As other guys have said before, some are indeterminate unless we make certain assumptions:

```
Limit[#, λ -> 0, Assumptions -> t ϵ/τ > 0] & /@f
```

$-\alpha  \tau +\alpha  \tau  e^{-\frac{t \epsilon }{\tau }}+\alpha  t$.

By the way. When I directly copy the mma code here from my notebook, it just show `\[Alpha]` but not $\alpha$ ? So I copy the latex here. Do you know some better mathods to copy mma code and keep the style?